# how to send a mail to contacts in particular label

Tags: gmail, label

I have bunch of emails from **from:do-not-reply@organisation.com** organisation but i can reply to the particular sender of the organisation **reply-to:sender@gmail.com**(all mails are from different senders) .. I marked all the mails from this organisation as seperate label called **my_label** ..

Now my problem is, How can i send(compose) the mail to all the senders in my label **my_label**??.

Kindly, help me!!. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Labels are for messages not for contacts, you can't do that. Instead you can create a contact group with all the senders:

- Create a new contact group.
- select all the emails from your label.
- drag and drop those emails into the new contact group.

Comment: How do you drag emails into a contact group? On the left side I only see a list of labels, not contact groups, into which emails can be dragged.

Comment: I think contact groups are now called circles

Comment: Nope. Circles are a different thing from Contact Groups that's used to organize your Google+ people.